# Intersect tool of ArcGis gives multiple intersecting points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, .net, intersect

I am using .net in arcGis 10.0 to develop tools.I have two polyline feature classes. I want to get intersected point of this 2 feature classes. for this purpose, I have used INTERSECT tool of arcmap. I want Just one intersected point of 2 features. But INTERSECT tool gives 4 points. How can I get one intersected point of two line feature ? Can I use another tool for this purpose??

I have an attached image .In the image, selected 4 feature denotes points in the intersected points. But I want one points.[image]

Comment: If you are using ArcObjects, which "I am using .net in arcGis 10.0 to develop tools" suggests, then I think our volunteers will need you to provide a code snippet that illustrates what you are doing.

Comment: Intersect geometry is created by You?  Maybe input data are 'broken'

Comment: @PolyGeo , thanks... here is my code snippet of intersect tool: 'var intersect = new Intersect
                                {
                                    in_features = gpValueTableObject,
                                    out_feature_class = _outputFeatureClass,
                                    join_attributes = _attributesToCopy.ToString(),
                                    output_type = _outputType.ToString()
                                };
            return intersect;'

Comment: I note that you have not yet taken the [tour].  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to post your code there where it can be formatted much more nicely.

Answer (score 3):

It's giving you 4 points because four lines end at that point. You can use the "Delete Identical" tool and chose the SHAPE field so that it removes all but one of the points as in my example below.

[image]